# How to make a long \twocolumn supertabular table fit within the page width?

Tags: tables, supertabular

I have a very long table that is just taking up too much space in my report. There is not THAT much information so I figured I can just print the table over two columns on one page, thus reducing page requirements by half. I found that the `supertabular` allows for this easily. However, it turns out my table is just a bit too wide to pull this off. I now want to put the table further on the left hand side so that it doesn't overlap like this, but any `\hspace` I put in seems to not have much impact. How can I move this to the left so that it fits properly?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn
\tablehead{\textbf{Code} &  \textbf{Branch} &   \textbf{Date and time} & \textbf{Duration} \\}

\begin{supertabular}{llll}

Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\
Q 383 & Branch Name 1 & Sep 19, 2015 09:00:00 - 09:44:00 & 44 min \\

\end{supertabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: Overlapping tables]

Comment: What makes you say that the structure is just a bit too wide to fit in a column. I'd say it's about 15% to 25% too wide to fit.

Comment: @Mico That's probably an underestimate, anyway, if the margins are taken into account. OP: I don't understand the aim here. If the information is important, it is worth laying it out in a way which makes it easy for people to access and read. If that means you need 2 or 4 pages (or whatever) rather than 1 or 2 (or whatever), that has to be worth it, doesn't it? If this is a large part of the report and the report is mostly for reference purposes, you might consider reducing the margins of the page, as the space will be less important for that kind of usage.

Comment: In this case the information is _not_ important, but it can't be left out. So my goal is to cram as much of it on a page as I can. I'll also decrease font size and want to simply have as little whitespace as possible. Few readers of this document will care about this table, but for administrative purposes it simply can't be left out.